# software engineering, GUI

Tags: java, eclipse

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Guiii extends JFrame{

  private JButton menu;
  private JButton custom;

  public Guiii(){
    super ("The Title");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    menu = new JButton("menu Button");
    add (menu);

    Icon b = new ImageIcon (getClass().getResource("button.png"));
    Icon x = new ImageIcon (getClass().getResource("greenbutton.png"));
    custom = new JButton("Custom",b);
    custom.setRolloverIcon(x);
    add (custom);


    HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
    menu.addActionListener(handler);
    custom.addActionListener(handler);

  }

  private class HandlerClass implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format("~s",     event.getActionCommand()));
    }   
  }
}
```

This is my code I am having some trouble and its not working, I have made a main for it but errors are showing can anyone help me and explain how the code will work **khg**

These are the errors

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:205)
    at Guiii.<init>(Guiii.java:22)
    at main.main(main.java:7)
```

This is the rest of the code but it had to be in another file:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Guiii o = new Guiii();
    o.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    o.setSize(300,200);
    o.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: What are the errors?..

Comment: [link]Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:205)
 at Guiii.<init>(Guiii.java:22)
 at main.main(main.java:7)

Comment: This isn't the complete code.right?

Comment: You can delete your comment with error since now it is part of question.

Comment: i have put the rest of the code in

Comment: `Foo.<init>`  represents constructor of `Foo` class. So `Guiii.<init>(Guiii.java:22)` means that problem is inside constructor of `Guiii` class at line 22. This line is `Icon b = new ImageIcon (getClass().getResource("button.png"));` and it is confirmed by `at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>` which suggests that problem is inside `ImageIcon` constructor. I suspect that you passed `null` as argument which means that `getClass().getResource("button.png")` returned `null`. If that is the case then this means your `button.png` is not inside same location as your `Guiii.class` file.

Comment: To help you more we would need to know about your project structure. You should also probably read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864267/load-icon-image-exception

Comment: do you know what the correct code would be

Comment: Correct code depends on your project structure and how you want to organize it.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor of the icon throws a NPE because `getResource` returns `null`.

Place the images in the same folder as the class Guiii.